# Does Superset support query/join multiple tables at a time?

Tags: apache-superset

It is said in the superset [documentation](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/faq.html#can-i-query-join-multiple-tables-at-one-time) that it is impossible to query/join multiple tables.

> Can I query/join multiple tables at one time?
> Not directly no. A Superset SQLAlchemy datasource can only be a single table or a view.

But from my experience I can do that without any problems. Is it outdated documentation, or something that I don't yet understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,superset sql lab support join multiple tables one time.

```html
select * from charles.m_jdbc_3 m left join druid.druid_supervisors d on m.id=d.id
where m.id={{id_value}} and m.value={{value_key}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do joins simply..

https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/875